# How to create multiple version of single post

Tags: posts

I am willing to create 2 pages for selected posts I have written. One in English language and another is in Hindi.

**Why not translator ?**

Translator translates many words in typical Hindi which makes a topic unclear to understand(even by myself). I want to keep combination of both Hindi & English words.

Comment: As your english seems to be quite good: Please rework your question, so the answer isn't a simply "yes/no" or gets close voted for being "not constructive" or "not a real question". We need answer to be some real task that has steps and can be answered in a way that it helps later visitors too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create another post under same categories with same title but `_hi` in last of paramlink.
2. Then add one more tag to all your hindi posts, say `hindi`.
3. Now exclude all the posts of `hindi` tag from default search or index.
4. Do the same with your English posts.
5. Give an option to opt language on all pages.
6. Filter posts as per selection.

Comment: +1 its a good trick. But I guess it'll require theme change and I'll have to repeat the same every time when I change the theme. Is there any plugin which can do all this task?